# jqgrid readonly combobox

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, jqgrid

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Database: Oracle10). I am using jqGrid to display records in tabular format.

I want to set `combobox` readonly in `Edit` dialog.

**colNames & colModel**

```
colNames:['User Name', 'Seq No.'],
colModel:[
            {name:'USER_ID',index:'USER_ID', width:200,sortable:true,editable:true,edittype:"select", editoptions: {maxlength: 20,dataUrl: 'ServletName?action=comboUserID'}},
            {name:'SEQUENCE_NUMBER',index:'SEQUENCE_NUMBER', width:50,sortable:true, editable:true, editrules: { required: true, number:true},editoptions: {size:4,maxlength: 2}}
         ],
```

**pager code**

```
).navGrid('#pager10_d1',{cloneToTop:true,edit:true,add:true,del:true,view:true,search: true},
                {
                    width:350,
                    modal:true,
                    jqModal: false,
                    savekey: [true,13],
                    closeOnEscape:true,
                    mtype:'POST',
                    closeOnSubmit: true,
                    recreateForm: true,
                    editurl:'MyServletName',
                    editData:
                    {
                        action: 'userRolesUPDATE',
                        userID: function () {return userID;}
                    },
                    beforeShowForm: function(form)
                    {
                        $('#USER_ID',form).attr('readonly','readonly');
                    }

                }
                //add dialog and other dialog code here
                );
```

I am [refering to this answer by Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952654/1551233) , but on my form it is not working, combobox is still editable. The Same code works for other `Field` in the grid, but it is not working for `combobox`.
So let me know if there is any mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `<select>` (combobox) can't be readonly. You can *disable* it instead using

```
$("#USER_ID", form).prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$("#USER_ID", form).attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

if you use old version of jQuery (before 1.6).